# error al hacer runserver en django (psycopg2)

Tags: python, django

desde un entorno virtual lanzo el server y me da este error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

intento instalar psycopg2 de mil formas

pip install psycopg2
pip install psycopg
pip install psycopg2-binary

todas me dan el mismo error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psicopg2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psicopg2

como puedo solucionar esto? gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se puede ver en la descripción del error que colocaste en la pregunta.

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for **psicopg2**

Y la librería se llama **psycopg2** (notar la diferencia de **ies**).

Procura escribir bien la siguiente instrucción:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Si no te funciona, intenta con:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org psycopg2
```

No está demás mencionar que deberás activar el entorno virtual con `activate`, previo a ejecutar estos comandos.

Comment: vale, soy un inútil. Estaba mal escrito... muchas gracias.